# Как каждую секунду к label прибавлять какое то значение qt?

Tags: c++, qt, qtcreator

Есть окно MainWindow в котором есть label_1 и label_2 в label_1 каждую секунду должно прибавляться значение label_2. К примеру в label_1 значение 0 а в label_2 значение 1 и каждую секунду к label_1 прибавляется label_2.

// mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

Comment: В чём суть вопроса? Вы не знаете как периодически вызывать метод? Или вы не знаете как к значению одной метки значение другой?

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev я не знаю как периодически вызывать метод

Comment: Используйте [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html).

Comment: @Sergey Gornostaev я знаю что нужно использовать QTimer, но я не понимаю как его использовать

Comment: По ссылке есть примеры.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [QTimer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html)

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    timer = new QTimer(this);
    timer->setInterval(1000);
    connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateLabel()));
    timer->start();
}

void MainWindow::updateLabel()
{
    QString value1 = ui->label_1->text();
    QString value2 = ui->label_2->text();
    ui->label_1->setText(QString::number(value1.toInt() + value2.toInt()));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Вероятно, имелось ввиду вот так:

```
void MainWindow::updateLabel()
{
    QString value1 = ui->label_1->text();
    QString value2 = ui->label_2->text();
    ui->label_1->setText(QString::number(value1.toInt() + value2.toInt()));
}
```

Или вот так:

```
void MainWindow::updateLabel()
{
    int value1 = ui->label_1->text().toInt();
    int value2 = ui->label_2->text().toInt();
    ui->label_1->setText(QString::number(value1 + value2));
}
```

Comment: Вы правы. Исправил ответ.